# Understanding what's available within Azure Platforms for Large Data

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

Our current Azure resources consist of a farm of 4 VMs running Windows Server 2012 R2.  3 of these VMs run web scraping jobs overnight, and write the results to a Database in SQL Server 2014 Standard - this SQL Server instance resides on the 4th VM.  Our current record count on our main table is 1.5 million rows, and we expect it to add approximately 500k rows per month.

Our current issue is with querying on the records in the database. It takes 10-20 seconds to return results where competitors are returning similar searches in milliseconds.  I can only see this issue getting worse as we continue piling the records into the database.  We have all possible indexing features turned on on the table and fields, and the query was constructed by a T-SQL expert with 20 years experience - therefore we don't believe either of these to be the issue.

My question is what, if any, product/resource can I (or should I) move to in Azure that could greatly increase performance?  I have watched countless videos on Azure in an effort to find this answer before coming here.  I tried to reach out to Microsoft directly, and of course they want more money (than the thousands we already pay them) just to talk to someone in support.  They suggest the Stack Overflow Azure tag for more immediate, "less-costly" support.

So here are my questions:

- Would a NoSQL db help me?
- Would a SQL Data Warehouse help me?
- Would an Azure cloud SQL DB (instead of a SQL Server db inside a VM) help me?

My company is in need of advice, and I hope some of you with Azure experience can offer just a little bit of your time. I've been researching this for days now.  Everyone on the net seems to be selling something.  I want to hear from the community who has experience with this.

UPDATE - I had a separate chat in a S/O Chat Room with @Rob_Reagan who was extremely helpful.  After answering several questions of his, he suggested Azure Search.  I've researched it and agree with this suggestion.  We are testing it now and the results are promising thus far.  I will return to mark this as answered once we confirm all tests are successful.  Many thanks to Rob and all other commenters.

Comment: To me this demonstrates quite a bit of research. However, it is most likely going to be closed because either it is too broad or it is primarily opinion based.

Comment: The answer is that it depends on exactly what you're trying to do. You mention web scraping and serving queries based on that data. Can you give us a little more detail on exactly what you're storing and how it needs to be queried?

Comment: This is really more of an architecture question rather  than a strict Azure question.  I'd love to help.  If only SO had private messages!

Comment: @CtrlDot, I believe that you can open a chat room for this question in case it gets shut down. If so, I'd love to join.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/141672/azure-platforms-for-large-data-understanding-whats-available-to-me

Comment: Thank you all for your comments thus far, I greatly appreciate it.  @SeanLange - if it gets closed, so be it.  I do appreciate your input.

Comment: I will go to this chat link now.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @halfer the edits are appreciated, thanks.